# How terminate a thread?

Tags: multithreading, delphi

My usual setup for a thread is a while loop and inside the while loop do two things:

- do some work
- Suspend, until resumed from outside

```
procedure TMIDI_Container_Publisher.Execute;
begin
   Suspend;
   while not Terminated do
   begin
      FContainer.Publish;
      if not Terminated then Suspend;
   end; // if
end; // Execute //
```

This works fine. To terminate the code I use:

```
destructor TMIDI_Container_Publisher.Destroy;
begin
   Terminate;
   if Suspended then Resume;
   Application.ProcessMessages;
   Self.WaitFor;

   inherited Destroy;
end; // Destroy //
```

This Destroy works fine in Windows 7 but hangs in XP. The problem seems to be the WaitFor but when I remove this the code hangs in the `inherited Destroy`.

Anybody ideas what is wrong?

---

Update 2011/11/02
Thanks to you all for your help. Remy Labeau came with a code example to avoid Resume/Suspend at all. I'll implement his suggestion in my programs from now on. For this specific case I was inspired by the suggestion of CodeInChaos. Just create a thread, let it do the publish in the Execute and forget about it. I used Remy's example to rewrite one of my timers. I post this implementation below.

```
unit Timer_Threaded;

interface

uses Windows, MMSystem, Messages, SysUtils, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
     Dialogs, SyncObjs,
     Timer_Base;

Type
   TTask = class (TThread)
   private
      FTimeEvent: TEvent;
      FStopEvent: TEvent;
      FOnTimer: TNotifyEvent;

   public
      constructor Create;
      destructor Destroy; override;
      procedure Execute; override;
      procedure Stop;
      procedure ProcessTimedEvent;

      property OnTimer: TNotifyEvent read FOnTimer write FOnTimer;
   end; // Class: TWork //

   TThreadedTimer = class (TBaseTimer)
   private
      nID: cardinal;
      FTask: TTask;

   protected
      procedure SetOnTimer (Task: TNotifyEvent); override;

      procedure StartTimer; override;
      procedure StopTimer; override;

   public
      constructor Create; override;
      destructor Destroy; override;
   end; // Class: TThreadedTimer //

implementation

var SelfRef: TTask; // Reference to the instantiation of this timer

procedure TimerUpdate (uTimerID, uMessage: cardinal; dwUser, dw1, dw2: cardinal); stdcall;
begin
   SelfRef.ProcessTimedEvent;
end; // TimerUpdate //

{*******************************************************************
*                                                                  *
* Class TTask                                                      *
*                                                                  *
********************************************************************}

constructor TTask.Create;
begin
   FTimeEvent := TEvent.Create (nil, False, False, '');
   FStopEvent := TEvent.Create (nil, True,  False, '');

   inherited Create (False);

   Self.Priority := tpTimeCritical;
end; // Create //

destructor TTask.Destroy;
begin
   Stop;
   FTimeEvent.Free;
   FStopEvent.Free;

   inherited Destroy;
end; // Destroy //

procedure TTask.Execute;
var two: TWOHandleArray;
    h:   PWOHandleArray;
    ret: DWORD;
begin
   h := @two;
   h [0] := FTimeEvent.Handle;
   h [1] := FStopEvent.Handle;

   while not Terminated do
   begin
      ret := WaitForMultipleObjects (2, h, FALSE, INFINITE);
      if ret = WAIT_FAILED then Break;
      case ret of
         WAIT_OBJECT_0 + 0: if Assigned (OnTimer) then OnTimer (Self);
         WAIT_OBJECT_0 + 1: Terminate;
      end; // case
   end; // while
end; // Execute //

procedure TTask.ProcessTimedEvent;
begin
   FTimeEvent.SetEvent;
end; // ProcessTimedEvent //

procedure TTask.Stop;
begin
   Terminate;
   FStopEvent.SetEvent;
   WaitFor;
end; // Stop //

{*******************************************************************
*                                                                  *
* Class TThreaded_Timer                                            *
*                                                                  *
********************************************************************}

constructor TThreadedTimer.Create;
begin
   inherited Create;

   FTask := TTask.Create;
   SelfRef := FTask;
   FTimerName := 'Threaded';
   Resolution := 2;
end; // Create //

// Stop the timer and exit the Execute loop
Destructor TThreadedTimer.Destroy;
begin
   Enabled := False;  // stop timer (when running)
   FTask.Free;

   inherited Destroy;
end; // Destroy //

procedure TThreadedTimer.SetOnTimer (Task: TNotifyEvent);
begin
   inherited SetOnTimer (Task);

   FTask.OnTimer := Task;
end; // SetOnTimer //

// Start timer, set resolution of timesetevent as high as possible (=0)
// Relocates as many resources to run as precisely as possible
procedure TThreadedTimer.StartTimer;
begin
   nID := TimeSetEvent (FInterval, FResolution, TimerUpdate, cardinal (Self), TIME_PERIODIC);
   if nID = 0 then
   begin
      FEnabled := False;
      raise ETimer.Create ('Cannot start TThreaded_Timer');
   end; // if
end; // StartTimer //

// Kill the system timer
procedure TThreadedTimer.StopTimer;
var return: integer;
begin
   if nID <> 0 then
   begin
      return := TimeKillEvent (nID);
      if return <> TIMERR_NOERROR
         then raise ETimer.CreateFmt ('Cannot stop TThreaded_Timer: %d', [return]);
   end; // if
end; // StopTimer //

end. // Unit: MSC_Threaded_Timer //


unit Timer_Base;

interface

uses
  Windows, MMSystem, Messages, SysUtils, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs;

type
   TCallBack = procedure (uTimerID, uMessage: UINT; dwUser, dw1, dw2: DWORD);

   ETimer = class (Exception);

{$M+}
   TBaseTimer = class (TObject)
   protected
      FTimerName: string;     // Name of the timer
      FEnabled: boolean;      // True= timer is running, False = not
      FInterval: Cardinal;    // Interval of timer in ms
      FResolution: Cardinal;  // Resolution of timer in ms
      FOnTimer: TNotifyEvent; // What to do when the hour (ms) strikes

      procedure SetEnabled (value: boolean); virtual;
      procedure SetInterval (value: Cardinal); virtual;
      procedure SetResolution (value: Cardinal); virtual;
      procedure SetOnTimer (Task: TNotifyEvent); virtual;

   protected
      procedure StartTimer; virtual; abstract;
      procedure StopTimer; virtual; abstract;

   public
      constructor Create; virtual;
      destructor Destroy; override;

   published
      property TimerName: string read FTimerName;
      property Enabled: boolean read FEnabled write SetEnabled;
      property Interval: Cardinal read FInterval write SetInterval;
      property Resolution: Cardinal read FResolution write SetResolution;
      property OnTimer: TNotifyEvent read FOnTimer write SetOnTimer;
   end; // Class: HiResTimer //

implementation

constructor TBaseTimer.Create;
begin
   inherited Create;

   FEnabled    := False;
   FInterval   := 500;
   Fresolution := 10;
end; // Create //

destructor TBaseTimer.Destroy;
begin
   inherited Destroy;
end; // Destroy //

// SetEnabled calls StartTimer when value = true, else StopTimer
// It only does so when value is not equal to the current value of FEnabled
// Some Timers require a matching StartTimer and StopTimer sequence
procedure TBaseTimer.SetEnabled (value: boolean);
begin
   if value <> FEnabled then
   begin
      FEnabled := value;
      if value
         then StartTimer
         else StopTimer;
   end; // if
end; // SetEnabled //

procedure TBaseTimer.SetInterval (value: Cardinal);
begin
   FInterval := value;
end; // SetInterval //

procedure TBaseTimer.SetResolution (value: Cardinal);
begin
   FResolution := value;
end; // SetResolution //

procedure TBaseTimer.SetOnTimer (Task: TNotifyEvent);
begin
   FOnTimer := Task;
end; // SetOnTimer //

end. // Unit: MSC_Timer_Custom //
```

Comment: The inherited destroy calls WaitFor too. Don't know your problem but you aren't supposed to use Suspend or Resume. I'd use events to pause threads. What does the ProcessMessages do?

Comment: We don't know what's in `inherited Destroy`, so it's hard to say.  But as a general practice, `Suspend` and `Resume` shouldn't be used.  It's better to use a synchronization object (try `SyncObjs.TSimpleEvent`) and have your thread wait on it.

Comment: @Mason Since we are calling `Terminate`, `Resume`, `Suspend`, `WaitFor` etc., I think we can guess that `inherited Destroy` is `TThread.Destroy`. But you are quite right about `Suspend`, `Resume` and events.

Comment: @David: Probably... unless there's another layer in there somewhere, of course. You make a good point that `TThread.Destroy` also calls `WaitFor`, though.

Comment: What is 'FreeOnTerminate' set to?

Comment: Why on earth are you resuming after terminate?

Comment: @warren how else could you run to completion?

Comment: Weird.  Suspend is kind of broken. So the resume is required because of the suspend, which shouldn't be done either.

Comment: The class is indeed derived from TThread, sorry for omitting this. `TThread.destroy` uses exactly the same sequence as in the code example: `Terminate; if suspended then Resume; WaitFor;` so i can in fact omit the whole rigmarole. An `inherited destroy` should suffice.

Comment: Kind of, Arnold. It's true that the code in your destructor is redundant, but that doesn't mean that `inherited Destroy` will make things better. Since it does all the same things as your destructor, you'll still be susceptible to all the same race conditions. (Besides, if a method — even a destructor — does nothing but call the inherited one, you don't need to write anything at all; omit the descendant method entirely.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You really should not use `Suspend()` and `Resume()` like this. Not only are they dangerous when misused (like you are), but they are also deprecated in D2010+ anyway.  A safer alternative is to use the `TEvent` class instead, eg:

```
contructor TMIDI_Container_Publisher.Create;
begin
  fPublishEvent := TEvent.Create(nil, False, False, '');
  fTerminateEvent := TEvent.Create(nil, True, False, '');
  inherited Create(False);
end;

destructor TMIDI_Container_Publisher.Destroy;
begin
  Stop
  fPublishEvent.Free;
  fTerminateEvent.Free;
  inherited Destroy;
end;

procedure TMIDI_Container_Publisher.Execute;
var
  h: array[0..1] of THandle;
  ret: DWORD;
begin
  h[0] := fPublishEvent.Handle;
  h[1] := fTerminateEvent.Handle;

  while not Terminated do
  begin
    ret := WaitForMultipleObjects(2, h, FALSE, INFINITE);
    if ret = WAIT_FAILED then Break;
    case ret of
      WAIT_OBJECT_0 + 0: FContainer.Publish;
      WAIT_OBJECT_0 + 1: Terminate;
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TMIDI_Container_Publisher.Publish;
begin
  fPublishEvent.SetEvent;
end;

procedure TMIDI_Container_Publisher.Stop;
begin
  Terminate;
  fTerminateEvent.SetEvent;
  WaitFor;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer! I was looking for a way to avoid suspend/resume but hadn't looked well enough. I'll implement this code and see how this works.

Comment: It works with XP and 7! Thanks for this example code because this is a nice replacement of the Suspend/Resume statements. It also is the outline for a generic looping thread that I use a lot in my code.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know the answer to your question, but I think your code has at least one other bug:

I guess you have a method like the following:

```
procedure DoWork()
begin
  AddWork();
  Resume();
end;
```

This leads to a race-condition:

```
procedure TMIDI_Container_Publisher.Execute;
begin
   Suspend;
   while not Terminated do
   begin
      FContainer.Publish;
      // <= Assume code is here (1)
      if not Terminated then { Or even worse: here (2) } Suspend;
   end; // if
end; // Execute //
```

If you call `DoWork` and resume the thread while it's somewhere around (1) or (2) it will go back to suspension immediately.

If you call `Destroy` while execution is around (2) it will suspend immediately and most likely never terminate.

Comment: It contains 'Application.ProcessMessages', 'Suspend', 'Resume' and TThread.WaitFor'.  IME, that's four bugs, though I recognize that others may disagree.  We all know that suspend/resume control of threads is dangerous.  'TThread.WaitFor' is a shutdown-deadlock generator like 'Join' and A.P is nearly always an indicator of poor design or is actually pointless.

Comment: @martin what's wrong with WaitFor or join? Denying yourself the use of those makes synchronisation tricky.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - only tricky?  I was hoping for 'impossible'.  You may have guessed that I prefer message-passing.  I'm not sure which is greater, the number of apps that have massive bodges in an  attempt to shut down or the number of apps with poor performance because they are continually creating/destroying threads.  Note that I don't blame the OP for his/her problems - the Delphi examples were apalling when D3 came out and I suspect that they have not improved.  Result - decades of suboptimal, poor designs, eg. suspend/resume control  - straight out of the Delphi examples.

Comment: The race condition may occur, I had not thought of that. Your comment pointed another solution to me. I don't need the while loop. I just generate a new thread for each publishing event, set `FreeOnTerminate := True` and forget about it.

Comment: And that solved the problem for this case. The application works fine without hanging in either XP or 7. Thanks! A more fundamental solution Remy just posted below. That appears the solution for a thread that loops in a while loop. I'll try that.

Comment: Arnold, if your solution is really to create a new thread for every new event, you should consider using a *thread pool*. The OS provides one, and some of the Delphi threading libraries also have thread pools. That allows your program to continue triggering distinct events, but removes the overhead of creating and destroying lots of OS threads. The pool makes sure idle threads get reused.

Comment: I missed this remark of the threadpool. I will look into that. Thank you for bringing this up.

Answer (score 2):

There's certainly deadlock potential in that code. Suppose `Execute` and `Destroy` are running concurrently, and there's a context switch away from the `Execute` thread immediately after evaluating `not Terminated`, like this:

```
// Thread 1                      // Thread 2
if not Terminated then
                // context switch
                                 Terminate;
                                 if Suspended then Resume;
                                 Application.ProcessMessages;
                                 WaitFor;
                // context switch
  Suspend;
```

Now you're waiting for the termination of a suspended thread. That will never make progress. The inherited destructor also calls `Terminate` and `WaitFor`, so it's no surprise that removing code from your own destructor doesn't have much effect on your program's behavior.

Don't suspend the thread. Instead, make it wait for an event that signals that there's more data to process. At the same time, make it wait for another event to signal that the thread should terminate. (As an extension to that advice, don't bother calling `Terminate`; since it's not virtual, it's just not a useful method for terminating a thread that does anything non-trivial.)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out so clearly the race condition to me. I will work out your advice in a sample program, it appears to be a solution to the problem. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score -1):

try use suspended := false instead of resume.